# Insert int mysql without duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, sql-insert

I have a database { id, name, uuid, world, x, y, z }

How can i insert into this database, and if there exists any row where { world, x, y, z } are the same as in that I inserted, the old row gets deleted. I have id as PRIMARY KEY and set to AUTO_INCREMENT.

I searched this forum and google but didn't find anything that helped with my issue.

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need it deleted and replaced with a new id, or do you want it updated with the same id?

Comment: I'm not sure. I want it as simple as possible and to make as few queries to the database server as possible. If you have a solution where I keep the id, then that is perfect as long as it is done in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in
>   the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a
>   `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

So declare a `UNIQUE` index row columns (word, x, y, z) and then:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (name, uuid, world, x, y, z)
VALUES (
    -- your values here 
)
```

Comment: Accepted this for being the most direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into table(name, uuid, world, x, y, z)
    values (@name, @uuid, @world, @x, @y, @z)
    on duplicate key update name = values(name),
                            uuid = values(uuid);
```

The variables `@name` and so on are just place holders for your values.  This also assumes that `id` is auto-incremented, so it doesn't need to be inserted.

For this to work, you need a unique index on the four columns:

```
create unique index idx_table_world_x_y_z on table(world, x, y, z);
```

If these are already declared as a primary key, then this is not necessary.